# SSRS report permission is not working propoerly

Tags: reporting-services

hi i am working on SSRS report and all my reports are deployed in server with all the user permission but not sure why permission is not working sometimes when new user is providing permission.

as per my knowledge i know that i can set permission with 3 different ways.
1. Site level
2. folder Level
3. Report Level

when ever a new user need permisson to view the report, i follows the below.

Step: 1 opened the Reportmanager URL(http://toshiba-pc/MyReports) and click Home
Step : 2 clicking on "Folder Settings"
Step 3: Click on "New Role Assignment" and enter the domainname\TestUser with  "Browser" role and click ok and TestUser user is automatically adding into all the folder
problem : some of user is not appearing into all folders some of the user is appearing into all folders.

to avoid above problem, i added DomainName\TestUser into folder security and it's again not appearing for all reports security , so again i have to add this user into the reports where use has not added.

this is very difficult to go each report to check whether reports has permission or not?

is there anything i am missing to configure , please let me know.
do i need to set role(system user, system administrator) for all the users to site setting. i never add user into site setting..

Please any one let me know what i am missing to configure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default all permissions cascade to every item contained within the folder.  This means that providing someone Browser access on the Home folder will give them Browser access to everything on the site.

This inheritance stops if at any point you have individually changed the security context of any item in the Report Manager.  If you have ever done this, you will see the option to Revert to Parent Security when looking at that item's security settings:

[image]

Clicking this will remove the custom security context on that item and reset it to match the security context of the containing folder.

To find all items that have a security context different to that of your home directory so you can change them in the Report Manager (You can change this in the ReportServer database, but you run the risk of breaking your entire reporting catalogue and Microsoft will offer you no support for editing the database directly) run this query on the server which holds your ReportServer database:

```
select *
from ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
where PolicyID not in(select PolicyID
                        from ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
                        where Path = '' -- Home Path
                        and Name = ''   -- Home Folder
                        )
```